# Black screen between plymouth and lightdm

Tags: boot, lightdm, systemd, plymouth

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a custom ARM-based board. When it boots, I see the plymouth boot screen for two seconds, and then it jumps to a console screen with a blinking text cursor in the upper right for about five seconds, before X11 loads.

I checked systemd-analyze, and it does run plymouth-quit-wait.service immediately before starting lightdm. However, it is lightdm itself that shows the black screen and takes a couple of seconds to get into X.

Is there a way to keep the plymouth output a bit longer, and to make the transition to X11/lightdm a bit nicer?